# Not able to send one-to-one chat message using XMPP

Tags: xmpp

I'm sending a message to a user like so..

```
 @objc fileprivate func sendPressed() {
   if let text = self.textView?.text {
      sendMessage(text: text)
    }
 }
```

`sendMessage` is given like so...

```
  func sendMessage(text: String) {
    let element = XMLElement(name: XMPPConfig.Keys.GLInformation)
    element.addAttribute(withName: XMPPConfig.Keys.GLMessageType, stringValue: MessageType.text.rawValue)
    sendTheMessage(text, element: element)
  }
```

Finally, `sendTheMessage` is given as,

```
  fileprivate func sendTheMessage(_ body: String, element: XMLElement) {
    print("sendMessage \(body)")
    let message = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: RealmManager.shared.recipientUser?.JID)
    message.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: generateUUID())
    message.addBody(body)
    message.addReceiptRequest()
    sendElement(message)
  }
```

But the other user is not able to receive the message. When the message is being send the log that is printed is something like so...

```
    RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" lang="en" to="2419@xmpp.abcstage.in/7330044482810331514281698" 
from="2258@xmpp.abcstage.in" type="error" id="D59B969E-F33E-4FD2-BB4F-3ECD3BFD44B6"><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/><error code="406"
 type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">Your
 active privacy list has denied the routing of this stanza.</text></error><body>Kk</body></message>
```

What could be the reason for such an error..?

Answer (score 1):

From the log you posted yourself:

> Your active privacy list has denied the routing of this stanza.

Comment: yeah..Even I'm confused about that...:).Any idea as what has to be done...?

Comment: Either modify the active privacy list, so that it allows the routing of the stanza, or simooy disable the privacy list.